# Is there a better way to force LINQ-TO-SQL string comparison to be Case Insensitive?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql

What I have currently is this, that ignores the collation of the server.

```
Snacks.Where(x => string.Equals(x.Name.ToLower(), "CHOCOLATE".ToLower()))
```

The resultant SQL is:

```
-- Region Parameters
DECLARE @p0 NVarChar(1000) = 'chocolate'
-- EndRegion
SELECT [t0].[SnackID], [t0].[Name]
FROM [Snack] AS [t0]
WHERE (LOWER([t0].[Name]) IS NOT NULL) AND (LOWER([t0].[Name]) = @p0)
```

Is there anything better to force the comparison ignoring the case?

Comment: is "configure the SQL Server / db to be case insensitive" an option?

Comment: Relying in the DB collation isn't an ideal solution in my case. That's why I added "force" to the question :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the overload with two strings and comparison the following example is the one with Ignoring cases but there's another options you can look at here's a link for ore information [StringComparison MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparison(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
(string a, string b, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
```

Comment: although your answer is theoretically correct, it will not work in this case. OP is actually querying a database using LINQ_TO_SQL. The linq statement will be translated into a sql query. But since there is no equivalent in sql for this overload OP will just receive a `System.NotSupportedException` when using your solution

Comment: Sorry, but that overload that takes the StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase isn't supported in LINQ-TO-SQL, as @MongZhu says.